# How to cancel multiple requests being made in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I've got a `getList()` function in `SearchService`:

```
  public getList() {
    // http post call as an observable
    // pipe with a few map transformations
  }
```

In my `ListComponent` I create an Observable like so:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    list$ = searchService.getList();    
  }
```

and in the template I subscribe to the observable via async pipe:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="list$ | async as list; else showSpinner">
   <!-- content -->
</ng-container>
```

And this is the only place I subscribe to the `list$` observable, but when I check Dev Tools I see two requests:
[image]

**Things I've tried:**

1. I saw a few similar questions on StackOverflow, but no answer solved my problem.
2. Adding `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` didn't work either.
3. I've tried piping different methods to `getlist()` function, but to no avail:

`share`, `shareReplay`, `publishReplay`, `refCount`, `delay`, `debounceTime`, `distinctUntilChanged`, `take`, `first`.
I've also tried these methods on the `list$` observable, but the result is the same.

What am I missing here?

Comment: are both the calls POST? is the first one pre flight request (OPTION)?

Comment: @NithinKumarBiliya both are post calls

Comment: Have you verified that ListComponent's ngOnInit only gets called once?

Comment: @MikeJ lol is there any way to call ngOnInit more than once?

Comment: @Ruslan Yes, if the component is instantiated more than once.

Comment: @MikeJ the component is initiated only in one module once

Comment: is it possible to reproduce it on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)?

Comment: @NithinKumarBiliya no unfortunately, I'm using a private api and the project is huge and everything is interconnected

Comment: you can always mock up the POST call. Not needed to have the entire project on stackblitz.

Comment: also why is it a POST call? I haven't seen anyone using async pipe with a POST call

Comment: @NithinKumarBiliya I tried it in a such a mocked environment, I've also tried creating a new project but I couldn't reproduce that problem.
It's a post call, because some payload needs to be sent to receive the desired response.

Answer (score 0):

A simple existing request detection with a variable will work

```
  let requestMade:any = null;
  class Foo {
    public getList() {
      if (requestMade) return requestMade;
      requestMade = someRequest();
      return requestMade;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm returning the request in `getList()` call. I don't understand your point

Comment: store the request in `requestMade` and then return it. If its already there in `requestMade`  then you don't make the request.

Comment: that function is used in other modules too, so this approach will be incorrect for this context

Comment: If you ever want to remake the request from other functions then invalidate i.e.  `requestMade = null`